# To show $T$ bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be normed linear spaces and let $T:X\to Y$ be a linear map such that for every absolutely convergent series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n$, the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}Tx_n$ converges. I want to prove that $T$ is bounded. What I have done is as follows:

Let $(x_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence in $X$. Then for every $k\in \mathbb N$, there exists $n_k\in \mathbb N$ such that $\parallel x_n-x_m\parallel<\frac{1}{2^k}$ for all $n,m\geq n_k$. Assumuing $n_k<n_{k+1}$ for all $k\in \mathbb N$ we get $\parallel x_{n_k}-x_{k-1}\parallel<\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$ for each $k\geq 2$. Let $y_1=x_{n_1}$ and $y_k= x_{n_{k}}-x_{n_{k-1}} $ for $k\geq 2$. Now it is easy to show that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}y_k$  is absolutely convergent. Therefore, by hypothesis, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}Ty_k$ converges. But this gives $(x_{n_k})$ converges. How to proceed further? please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible proof, using a different argument, is this:

Assume $T$ is not bounded. Then for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ there is $z_k\in X$ with $\Vert z_k\Vert_X=1$ and $\Vert Tz_k\Vert_Y>k^2$. Now, consider the sequence $(x_k)_k$ s.t. for all $k$, $ x_k=\frac{z_k}{k^2}$. Then:

1. $\Vert Tx_k\Vert_Y>1$ for all $k$.
2. The series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k$ is absolutely convergent, which implies $\sum_{k=1}^\infty Tx_k$ is convergent.

Consider the sequence $(y_k)_k$ in $Y$ given by $y_k=\sum_{n=1}^k Tx_n$. By 2. it is a convergent sequence. However, by 1. for all $k$, $\Vert y_k-y_{k-1}\Vert_Y=\Vert Tx_k\Vert_Y >1$, which implies it is not a Cauchy sequence, which is a contradiction.